Author citation numbering using sequential letters
I'm submitting an article to a journal that has certain formatting requirements.
For the authors list, underneath the title, they want superscripted citations after each name in the form of "a)", "b)", "c)", etc. But for the rest of the article, the citations are to be in the form of superscripted numerals, starting at 1, 2, 3, etc.
So, first off, I'm using the following package to obtain superscripted numerals for citations:

\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

Next, when I use this line:

\textmd{Author B. One\Mark{a)}, Author B. Two\Mark{b)}}\

... it gives me the correct output: Author B. One with a superscripted a) at the end,
and Author B. Two with a superscripted b) at the end, etc.
BUT -- the regular citations in the text now start at 3 instead of 1.
So how can I restart the citation numbering in the text at 1?

In general, stackexchange sites prefers only one question per post. You can edit your post to remove one of the questions, and post a second question. At the moment, though, I suspect that you question can't reasonably be answered, because there are many ways to do things, and which to choose depends on other things, including the document class. If you provide a minimal working example ( MWE ), you stand a better chance of getting good answers.

Welcome! Note that TeXShop is just your editor. It doesn't tell us anything we need to know to help you.

Okay thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question to hopefully focus down on the main issue I'm having.
